# How to invoke a JSF bean action from a link?

Tags: jsf, hyperlink, window, managed-bean

We have the following requirement in our project.

On click of a link,

1. A JSF managed bean method should be invoked which will return a URL
   to a document.
2. This document should be opened in a new window.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the JSF version you use ? Are you using any additional component library like Richfaces ?

Comment: We are using JSF1.2. We don't have any third pary component library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a `<h:commandLink/>` with a `target="_blank"` attribute:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.action}" target="_blank" value="Open document"/>
```

And in your bean:

```
public void action() {
   try {
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .redirect("page2.xhtml");
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       // do something here
   }
}
```

Replace `page2.xhtml` with your target url.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks alot. This works!
Is there anyway to do this without using javascript? I mean the commandLink uses javascript.